# Find at least one first order differential equation from general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I find at least one first order differential equation when the solution for it is $y = x^4$?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most basic equation would be simply $ \frac {dy}{dx}$ = 4$x^3$
with initial condition that **y(0)=0**

You can get **infinite** solutions by introducing some **constant terms** or **some specific f(x)**, and restricting them with specific **initial conditions**.

For eg. take $$ \frac {dy}{dx}  = 4x^3+k$$ (where k is some constant)

So, $$dy=(4x^3+k)dx$$
integrating both sides,
$$y=x^4+kx+c$$
Now, use **y(0)=0**

How about taking $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = (4x^3 + px^q + r)?$$
$$y=x^4+ \frac {px^{q+1}}{q+1}+rx+c$$
Again, **y(0)=0**

Comment: Can you find more?

Comment: edited...just keep changing k and you get infinite solutions